Airflow DAG Throws Random Error: Temporary failure in name resolution
We are using Airflow 2.6. We have our Airflow instances hosted in AWS.
There is a number of DAGs which had been running without issue for a number of years now, however we keep running into the below error which appears randomly it seems on various nodes within the DAGs.
There doesn't appear to be any pattern to this at all which has caused us some concern. We have tried AWS support and they seem to rule out any issues with the AWS instances so hoping to get some help here.
To reduce the impact of the issue, we have set the retry option on our DAGs to try and reduce the failure counts.
Any help greatly appreciated.
((psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "XXX.rds.amazonaws.com" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
To reduce the impact of the issue, we have set the retry option on our DAGs to try and reduce the failure counts.
